# How to inject logic into javascript in HAML?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, haml

I'm attempting to add Mercury editor and while modifying the layout for it, it suggests to add some javascript into the view layout.  Obviously the following won't quite work, but it expresses the gist of what I'm attempting to accomplish.  You'll want to look at the section within the :javascript filter, on down where I add the `-` to begin the if statement for what I mean:

```
  ...
  %body{ :class => "#{controller_name} #{action_name}" }
    :javascript
      var saveUrl = null; // Set to the url that you want to save any given page to.
      var options = {
        saveStyle: null,  // 'form', or 'json' (default json)
        saveMethod: null, // 'POST', or 'PUT', (create, vs. update -- default POST)
        visible: null     // if the interface should start visible or not (default true)
      };

      //<!-- Mix in any configurations provided through Rails.application.config.mercury_config -->
      - if Rails.application.config.respond_to?(:mercury_config)
        jQuery.extend(Mercury.config,
        = Rails.application.config.mercury_config.to_json.html_safe
        );
      - end

      //<!-- Mix in any options for PageEditor provided through Rails.application.config.mercury_page_editor_config -->
      - if Rails.application.config.respond_to?(:mercury_page_editor_config)
        jQuery.extend(options,
        = Rails.application.config.mercury_page_editor_config.to_json.html_safe
        );
      - end

      //<!-- Instantiate the PageEditor -->
      new Mercury.PageEditor(saveUrl, options);
      ...
```

**Could you please provide an example of how to do this properly?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could extract your logic to helper methods and then simply interpolate their results. Take a look.

```
# page_helper.rb

def mercury_config
  if Rails.application.config.respond_to?(:mercury_config)
    "jQuery.extend(Mercury.config,
       #{Rails.application.config.mercury_config.to_json.html_safe}
    );"
  end
end

def mercury_page_editor_config
  if Rails.application.config.respond_to?(:mercury_page_editor_config)
    "jQuery.extend(options,
        #{Rails.application.config.mercury_page_editor_config.to_json.html_safe}
    );"
  end
end

# your_view.html.haml

:javascript
  var saveUrl = null; // Set to the url that you want to save any given page to.
  var options = {
    saveStyle: null,  // 'form', or 'json' (default json)
    saveMethod: null, // 'POST', or 'PUT', (create, vs. update -- default POST)
    visible: null     // if the interface should start visible or not (default true)
  };

  //<!-- Mix in any configurations provided through Rails.application.config.mercury_config -->
  #{mercury_config}

  //<!-- Mix in any options for PageEditor provided through Rails.application.config.mercury_page_editor_config -->
  #{mercury_page_editor_config}

  //<!-- Instantiate the PageEditor -->
  new Mercury.PageEditor(saveUrl, options);
```

Comment: In this case it's being included in the layout file as per noted above.  It appears that you have to use application_helper.rb vs creating a helper for a layout.  Or is there another approach that would be better in this case?